# java how to update an instance in a method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Ok, I am confused. I try to update a value of an instance in a method in an interface.

```
public interface ICalculationMethods {

    static void matchMonitor(Game game) {
        Player player1 = game.getPlayer1();
        Player player2 = game.getPlayer2();
        int scorePlayer1 = 0;
        int scorePlayer2 = 0;
        List<Toss> tossListPlayer1 = new ArrayList<Toss>();
        List<Toss> tossListPlayer2 = new ArrayList<Toss>();
        tossListPlayer1.add(game.getToss1());
        tossListPlayer2.add(game.getToss2());
        if (winnerOfThisGame(game) == 0) {
            scorePlayer1++;
        } else if (winnerOfThisGame(game) == 1) {
            scorePlayer2++;
        }
        if (checkIfmatchIsover(game)) {
            if (scorePlayer1 > scorePlayer2) {
                player1.setTotalpoints(player1.getTotalpoints() + 1);
            } else if (scorePlayer1 < scorePlayer2) {
                player2.setTotalpoints(player2.getTotalpoints() + 1);
            }
        }
    }System.out.println(player2);
```

the outcome is Player [id=2, name=Marianna Horne, totalpoints=1]

Marianna Horne actualy has a totalpoints=9 in the database. It looks like inside the scope of this method this instance is more like temporary copy. Am I not getting the very basic concept method scoop ? Is there a way to actualy update this value in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you implemented the methods in whatever `Game` class you created. If the `getPlayer1()` simply returns a new instance of a `Player` with the stats of the original, the `Player` in the `Game` object you pass in will not change at all. Instead you should return the actual pointer to the `Player` you want to modify.

However, I am not too sure about this database you are referring to. If you mean the contents `Game` object, then simply do what I said above. But if there is some other external database, you might need to update that too within the `setTotalPoint()` method or somewhere else